# RegExp different results on different sites

Tags: javascript, regex

This regExp gives different results: (([0-9]+(.))[0-9]+)+ matching '0000' but it shouldn't.

What i want to match is 1.1.1 or 12.121.21 or 12312412.214214.21.241412.

The same RegExp on the site http://regexr.com/ doesn't match the '0000' but on the jsFiddle side it does.

Working example is : https://jsfiddle.net/swek7ar0/2/ .

```
var regExp = new RegExp("(([0-9]+(\.))+[0-9]+)+");
console.log(regExp.test('0000'));
```

Comment: `var regExp = /(([0-9]+(\.))[0-9]+)+/;`

Comment: `var regExp = new RegExp("(([0-9]+(\\.))+[0-9]+)+");`

Comment: Now it fails everywhere. This isn't a solution. But Avinash Raj solution works.